# How to only show variables created from a file (out of many) in RStudio workspace?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two R script files opened in R Studio (i.e. those "tabs" on top) and I have run both of them. The variables created from these 2 files are shown in the workspace pane in the upper right of R studio.

Is there a way to only show those variables created from that file being currently used? e.g. variable created from file #1 is shown when I switch to the file #1 tab)?
For example:
[image]

I am ok with selectively deleting those variables from the other (not being used) files too. But I can't find a way to remove all variables generated from a certain file, without having to list the variables out one by one.